# GitHub PR validation with .NET MAUI iOS app

Tags: github-actions, maui

I have an open source .NET MAUI app that builds for iOS, Android and Windows. As part of the PR validation, I would like to run a build for all 3 platforms to ensure everything is compilable.
This works for Android and Windows, but for iOS I need to have the proper certificate and provisioning profile installed. I have them as base 64 in a secret and decode and install them in the action, which works for my PRs. But since secrets are not passed down to PRs from outside contributors, the validation fails for them.
What is the best practice for such a scenario?